# C++ command line size

Tags: c++, terminal

I have a few general questions about writing C++ programs and running them from Unix shells.  Is there a way to ask the shell for it's size?  Either in pixels, characters, whatever?  What about relocating the cursor within the window?  How would you do this if you needed to?

Answer (score 2):

With the [`ncurses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library, getting the terminal width (in characters) is as easy as calling the function [`getmaxx`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxx). Similarly, [`getmaxy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxy) returns the height, and [`getmaxyx`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxyx) gets them both at once.

The cursor can be moved by calling [`move`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/move) with the *x* and *y* coordinates.

Comment: Actually, `LINES` and `COLS` are the usual place to get the screen-size, subject to `use_env`.  The getmax* functions are for a given window, which could be smaller than `stdscr`.

Answer (score 0):

Check [NCURSES](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) it is what I think you are looking for.